# How to Create a Custom Extension in Tiptap-Vuetify for a Tag/Replace Functionality?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, tiptap

I'm working on a project that uses Vuetify, Tiptap, and Tiptap-Vuetify. I want to create a custom extension that adds a new functionality to the toolbar. Specifically, I want to add a button that, when clicked, opens a dialog allowing the user to choose a tag (e.g., %example%). This tag should then be inserted into the editor at the cursor's position.

Additionally, I'd like to parse this tag and display a preview of how the content will look after being processed. The tag should be non-editable, except for the delete operation.

I've looked through the documentation and examples, but I haven't found a guide on how to create a new extension for this purpose. I'm also unsure whether the extension should be created at the Tiptap level or the Tiptap-Vuetify level.

Has anyone done something similar or have any ideas on how to approach this?